# Close matMenu on Dialog Open?

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design

I am triggering a dialog on clicking an item in matMenu but the concern is that matMenu doesn't close when dialog is open.
I want it to close it as soon as dialog box opens up, it closes  when you click somewhere in the page, but I want it to close once dialog box opens.

this is the code-snippet for matMenu.

```
  <button mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" #menuTrigger="matMenuTrigger" (mouseup)="menuTrigger.closeMenu()">
    <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
  </button>
  <mat-menu #menu="matMenu" xPosition="before" >
    <button mat-menu-item (click)="openUpdateQuestionDialog($event,currentSelectedQuestion)">
      Edit
    </button>
    <button mat-menu-item (click)="confirmDeleteQuestion($event,currentSelectedQuestion)">
      Delete
    </button>
  </mat-menu>
```

I am trying different ways to make it work, but no luck.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a couple of options for closing the mat menu (mat menu trigger).

[From the docs](https://material.angular.io/components/menu/overview#toggling-the-menu-programmatically), you can use the matMenuTrigger from the ts via a "child" decorator ([ViewChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) or [ContentChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ContentChild) potentially based on your location of the menu to the functionality):

```
class MyComponent {
  @ViewChild(MatMenuTrigger) trigger: MatMenuTrigger;

  someMethod() {
    this.trigger.closeMenu(); // <-- put this in your dialog open method
  }
}
```

I did not test this, but it may also be possible to call the close from the template as well:

```
<button mat-menu-item
  (click)="openUpdateQuestionDialog($event,currentSelectedQuestion) && menuTrigger.closeMenu()"
>
```

Comment: There are 4 must haves that worked for me: 
`1. menu with an id like #menu="matMenu,
2. calling menuTrigger.closeMenu() in the template
3. having @ViewChild(MatMenuTrigger) trigger: MatMenuTrigger;
4. explicit calling this.trigger.closeMenu();
` Also @bugs answer help in figuring this out.

Comment: The bottom example should be `(click)="openUpdateQuestionDialog($event,currentSelectedQuestion); menuTrigger.closeMenu()"` have tested it works.

Answer (score 5):

You can do that by calling `closeMenu()` on the `MatMenuTrigger` directive (see [here](https://material.angular.io/components/menu/api#MatMenuTrigger) for docs).

Something like

```
<button mat-button #menuTrigger="matMenuTrigger" [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">Menu</button>
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
</mat-menu>

---

@ViewChild('menuTrigger') trigger;
...
this.trigger.closeMenu()
```

---

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jgwmeu)

Answer (score -1):

Without @ViewChild:

```html
<mat-menu #moreMenu="matMenu" #menuTrigger="matMenuTrigger" [matMenuTriggerFor]="moreMenu">
  <button mat-menu-item (click)="doYourThing(); menuTrigger.closeMenu()">More</button>
</mat-menu>
```